# Building a table from two lists taking every element from the 1st list and every 5th from the 2nd

Tags: list-manipulation

How do you get a conditional to work in the bounds of a Table:

```
Table[{A[[i]], "->", B[[j]]}, {i, 2}, {j, If[j = 1, 5, (5*i)]}]
```

`j`always evaluates to 5

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `A=Table[r,{r,5}];B=Table[q,{q,10}];Table[{A[[i]], "->", B[[ If[j == 1, 5, (5*i)]]]}, {i, 2}, {j,2}]` and see if that is what you want. If this doesn't solve your problem then please edit the question to help me understand what you are trying to do. Also look up `=` and `==` in the help system and try to see the difference in those.

Comment: That will work Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `j` is always 5 because you write

```
If[j = 1, 5, (5*i)]
```

when you should write

```
If[j == 1, 5, (5*i)]
```

That is, you are assigning 5 to `j`, not testing to see if it is equal to 1.
But note, since 5 is the same as 5*1, you just want `j` to be `5*i` for all `i`. Therefore, you don't need `j` at all but can just write

```
Quiet @ Table[{A[[i]], "->", B[[5 i]]}, {i, 2}]
```

> `{{A[[1]], "->", B[[5]]}, {A[[2]], "->", B[[10]]}}`

Comment: I have 2 files A and B. I want to combine them . For every entry in A I want to associate the first 5 entries of B
A[1]->B[1]
.
.
A[1]->B[5]

Then
A[2]->B[6]
.
.
A[2]->B[10]

So for every line in A, I will have 5  lines from B
File will look like this
A[1]->B[1]
A[1]->B[2]
A[1]->B[3]
A[1]->B[4]
A[1]->B[5]
A[2]->B[6]
A[2]->B[7]
......

The issue with the Table Form is that I need the change the imin.
Table[expr,{i,imin,imax}]

I am not sure a Table form  can do this.

Comment: Please disregard. Whole issue has been resolved.

Thank You for your time

Michel